# How to Align an element under an equal paragraph

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to align an element e.g. button under an  uneven paragraph. For example, one paragraph contains 3 lines, second contains 2 lines and third contain 5 lines

I tried using position absolute but it does not appear to work.
each paragraph are separated by a div container so I have 3 container with a paragraph and a button on each

```
button{
position: absolute;
bottom:30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create us a demo on jsfiddle or equivalent? It is hard to tell you where you went wrong without us being able to see the HTML structure as well as applied CSS

Comment: please refer to the comment below

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to give each of your paragraphs a `min-height`. You would have to determine what that height would be before-hand, and make sure that it's a good number that will fit most, if not all, cases of varying height paragraphs.

```css
.section {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-right:15px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
p {
  min-height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class='section'>
<p>kfsa jfdsajkfsaeifj asfj asdjfaks asdfjkasdf dsafj dsaf jdsaf jsak jfldsa jfkdsa</p>
<button>Click here!</button>
</div>

<div class='section'>
<p>kfsa jfdsajkfsaeifj asfj asdjfaks asdfjkasdf dsafj dsaf jdsafasdjfaks asdfjkasdf dsafj dsaf jdsaf jsak jfldsa jfkdsa</p>
<button>Click here!</button>
</div>

<div class='section'>
<p>kfsa jfdsajkfsaeifj asfj asdjfaks asdfjkasdf dsafj dsaf jdsafasdjfaks asfj asdjfaks asdfjkasdf dsafj dsaf jdsafasdjfaks asdfjkasdf dsafj dsaf jdsaf jsak jfldsa jfkdsa</p>
<button>Click here!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: its a nice idea but the problem would be the alignment on the top. is it possible to equalize the top  with uneven bottom but  equal button position at the bottom?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just set the `vertical-align` property to `top`. Check my updated answer.